# What does mathchar do?

Tags: math-mode, symbols, tex-core

The package [`cmll`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/cmll) defines `\with` (looks like '&') as

```
$ texdef -t latex -p cmll with

\with:
\mathchar"2026


\the\with:
8230
```

When I take a look at `\&` it is defined as

```
texdef -t latex \&          

\&:
\char"26


\the\&:
38
```

So `\with` and `\&` seem to be different, although the resuls look identical to me. What is the difference?

Comment: I really have no idea how to tag this question. Please feel free to adjust it, if `tex-core` was not appropriate.

Comment: Is `\with` allowed only in math mode?

Comment: @Sigur A command defined with `\mathchardef` (or `\DeclareMathSymbol`) can only be used in math mode.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

The four hexadecimal digits `"kfab` in a `\mathchar` specify

- `k` is the atom type (0 = ordinary, 1 = operator, 2 = binary operation, 3 = relation, 4 = opening, 5 = closing, 6 = punctuation, 7 = variable family);
- `f` the math group (font family) where the glyph should be taken from;
- `ab` the slot in the font.

One can use `\mathchar<15 bit number>` directly or define

```
\mathchardef<cs>=<15 bit number>
```

so, for instance, after `\mathchardef\with="2026` the command `\with` is equivalent to typing `\mathchar"2026` (or `\mathchar8230`, for `"` specifies hexadecimal number).

Typing `\char<8 bit number>` tells TeX to use the character from the current font in the specified slot. However, when in math mode, `\char"ab` is equivalent to saying `\mathchar"00ab`, so ordinary symbol from math group 0 and the same slot. The `\chardef` command is the counterpart of `\mathchardef` and, indeed, `\&` is usually defined as

```
\chardef\&="26
```

<sub>Small lie: it's `` \chardef\&=`& ``, but it's not really important.</sub>

There is a big difference between `$x \mathchar"2026 y$` and `$x \char"26 y$`, or, with the definitions above

```
$x \with y$

$x \& y$
```

[image]

In the first case the `&` symbol is spaced as it's good for a binary operation, in the second case no space is added, because we're specifying three ordinary symbols.

Comment: Which font does `\mathchar` use (per default, if there are multiple ones)? Are there other ways than using latex to look at this font?

Comment: @moose The font is the one specified in the “math group”; there are four predefined ones: 0 usually is the standard text font, 1 is the math italic font, 2 is the symbol font and 3 is the large symbols font. Math font packages set them.

Comment: I also see some packages using `\mathchardef` just to hold a number, like a register (not to ultimately typeset a symbol in mathematics)... why? Edit: Ah I see answers here: [Why to store a number via chardef?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/244118/why-to-store-a-number-via-chardef/48) and here: [Macro vs counter: How to store and operate with numbers in TeX without using (too many) counters](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/55951/macro-vs-counter-how-to-store-and-operate-with-numbers-in-tex-without-using-to/48).

Comment: @ShreevatsaR One of Knuth's optimization: you can use a `\chardef` or `\mathchardef` token whenever TeX is looking for a `<number>`

Comment: Do you have a link where we can read about this?

Comment: @CarlosPinzón The TeXbook is the definitive source, but also TeX by Topic: `texdoc texbytopic` or https://texdoc.org/serve/texbytopic/0