# Is there a numbered list of characters that \mathchar uses?

Tags: math-mode, symbols

I was playing with [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/101136/48773) by Steven B. Segletes, and in it, it uses the character `\mathchar"0362`. How did (or, could) he find that 0362 is the right number to use?

I found this [related answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/229705/48773) which explains that (a) the 4 numbers are hexadecimal, and (b) are grouped into 3 groups, but I still don't know how to find the characters other than manually typing into my `.tex` file.

I know how to code so I could automate a .tex file using for loops, and then compile that, but I was wondering if there was another (better?) way.

Comment: The first hexadecimal digit tells TeX the kind of symbol (ordinary, operator, relation, binary relation, etc.); the second digit specifies the math font family; the last two digits specify the slot in the font. There can be no “list”, because the assignments of fonts to familes are not fixed and may depend on the document.

Comment: Are you by chance looking for the `fonttable` package that allows you to create tables of these characters?

Answer (score 6):

As explained in https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/229705/, the four hexadecimal digits specify the mathematical type of the symbol, the math font family and the slot in the font.

There is no “list of mathchars”. The LaTeX kernel sets up font families 0, 1, 2 and 3, which are mandatory in order that math can be typeset. However, font packages can change the assignments, adding new families or symbols, or even changing slots.

For instance, the LaTeX kernel defines

```
\DeclareMathSymbol{\parallel}{\mathrel}{symbols}{"6B}
```

whereas `fourier.sty` defines

```
\DeclareMathSymbol{\parallel}{\mathrel}{symbols}{141}
```

In both cases, `symbols` refers to math family 2, and the result is that `\parallel` in the LaTeX kernel is essentially equivalent to `\mathchar"326B`, but with `fourier` it becomes `\mathchar"328D`.

The `stmaryrd` package provides additional symbols, for instance

```
\DeclareMathSymbol\shortleftarrow\mathrel{stmry}{"00}
```

and we can't even translate this directly into `\mathchar` syntax, because what font family number is assigned to `stmry` is not known in advance, depending on several different factors. This will be equivalent to

```
\mathchar"3<stmry>00
```

where `<stmry>` is some integer from 4 to 15 (translated into a hexadecimal digit).

Comment: @frougon Yes, you're right