# How to determine the kind of atom of a given mathematical symbol?

Tags: tex-core

Is there a way to determine the type of atom assigned by TeX to a given mathematical symbol? For example, I suspect that both `\exists` and `\forall` are "type 1" math atoms (namely, operators), but I am thinking "mathematically" in this case.

Comment: Related: [What does `\mathchar` do?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/229701/5764)

Comment: Both `\exists` and `\forall` are ordinary math symbols. See section **38.3.3 <mathchardef tokens>: ordinary symbols** (p 305) in [TeX by Topic](//texdoc.net/pkg/texbytopic).

Comment: Now that @Werner posted that link, take a look at the definition of, e.g., `\exists`. That one is `\mathchar"239`, so it is of family 2 and symbol `39`<sb>16</sb>. So it is not assigned class 1 (that would be a place befor `"239`). Compare `\mathchar"239 a` to `\mathchar"1239 a` to see the difference.

Comment: It's much simpler to do `\texttt{\meaning\exists}`, which yields `\mathchar"239` and interpreting the definition.